# bootstrap tooltips off-center in table cells with large content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with links in some of the cells. The text in these links  can be quite long. The overflow of the table cell is hidden so all of the cells are the same width. This causes a problem when I put a bootstrap tool-tip on the  tag since the tool-tip shifts to the right to center on the hidden width of the links text.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zjy1t9s7/

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <a data-original-title="666" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                    This link has an incredibly long text which shifts the entire tooltip outside of the table cell, I personally think this looks like shit and want to fix it. Let's see if I can reproduce it here.
                </a>
            </td>
                                                                                         <td >
                <a data-original-title="555" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                    These are not as big
                </a>
            </td>
            <td >
                <a data-original-title="555" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                    These are not as big
                </a>
            </td>
                                                                                          <td >
                <a data-original-title="555" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                    These are not as big
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

td {
    border:1px solid #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

Hover over the first table cell and see what I mean.

Is this fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing i tried was to add the tooltip-info to the td-tag. but that caused a little problem so i added a div-wrapper around it, which worked for me:

```
<td >
    <div data-original-title="666" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
        <a>
        This link has an incredibly long text which shifts the entire tooltip outside of the table cell, I personally think this looks like shit and want to fix it. Let's see if I can reproduce it here.
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

add css:

```
td > div {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjy1t9s7/1/

**EDIT: Easier solution without a div-wrapper**

add this to your css:

```
td > a {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

text-tags like *<a>*, *<span>*, *<b>* etc need to be defined as block-type displaystyle if you want to specify a *width* or use *padding*

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zjy1t9s7/2/

Comment: But I must ask, I tried setting max-width:100% and overflow hidden on the <a> tag before I posted here but that didn't work. Why? Why does a div work differently when it comes to those settings?

Comment: If you want to define a textfield to a specific width, it has to be set to a block-type display-style, like _block_, _inline-block_, etc.
i actually found an easier way to get what you tried to do. look in the answer to see the new fiddle

Comment: thank you, I still have a hard time with css sometimes so thank you for your explanation :)